# ANDROID System Recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery

I am in recovery mode option, to restore user data.  What file do I need to choose to recover  boot partition.I can apply from update, apply from cache, but still need to choose a file which one do I apply to get my phone to boot normally again so far I chose a frw , but when the I reboot the phone it stopped on starting android apps 32 of 135, then it turns off and repeats again . Never moving up than 32. please help to solve

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping the dalvik cache,
The dalvik cache stores app's code that has been optimized to run on that particular set of hardware (CPU architecture).

If you wipe the dalvik cache, android will "optimize" all the apps, and maybe the 32-34th app will start.

Edit: In order to suggest a better solution if that fails, can you please answer the following questions.

1. Is the device rooted?
2. Do you have custom recovery installed? If so, which one?
3. Do you have a warranty that you don't want to lose from trying recovery options?

Comment: no it is not rooted ,and i am not trying to be rude but,  if i had a custom recovery file ,i doubt we would be having this  exchange.i have no file with that name all i have are basic android files like,DCMC, and , image,downloads, games,and the such if i click on recovery, the only file that comes up is .../ thats it, if i click on it all it does is say ... no file chosen please choose a file ans press vol.down to select. there is no other file.

Comment: @TATTIANNAAMARA that sounds like you have to do a [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) then.

Comment: been there and done that same thing happens,.